# Solution in common for two differential equations

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus

Consider:

$E1: y''-4y'+4y=0$

Solution: $y(x)=c_1 e^{2x}+c_2 x e^{2x} $

$E2: y''-2ay'+(a^2-1)y=0$

Solution: $y(x)=c_1 e^{(a+1)x}+c_2 e^{(a-1)x} $

For what values of $a$, $E1$ and $E2$ have solutions in common?.

At first glance, i see that if $a=1$ and $c_2=0$ there is a solution in common wich is: $y(x)=c_1 e^{2x}$

However i dont know if there is another values of $a$, so im looking for a more procedural approach. First i derive the solution of $E1$ three times, then i plug them in $E2$.

$4e^{2x}(c_1+c2 x+c_2) -2ae^{2x}(2c_1+2c_2x+c_2)+(a^2-1)e^{2x}(c_1+c_2x)=0$

$e^{2x}(4(c_1+c2 x+c_2) -2a(2c_1+2c_2x+c_2)+(a^2-1)(c_1+c_2x))=0$

Im stuck here, i dont know how to check for what vaues of a, on every x, the equation holds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $E_2$, we have:

$$m^2 -2 a m + a^2 - 1 = 0 \implies m_{1,2} = a-1, a+ 1$$

For $E_1$, we have a double root of $m = 2$.

Since we want to find a solution that is in common, we can equate each root from $E_2$ with $E_1$ and we have:

$$a - 1 = 2 \implies a = 3 \\ a+ 1 = 2 \implies a = 1$$

Comment: That make sense, however i dont know if that method would work for non-homogeneous diff. equations. I think i must reach the same result that yours with $e2x(4(c1+c2x+c2)−2a(2c1+2c2x+c2)+(a2−1)(c1+c2x))=0$, what you can say from the equations $c_2x(a^2-4a+3)=0$, $c_1(a^2-4a+3)=0$?. That polynomials have roots $a=1$ and $a=3$... dont know what to conclude with this...